# Laravel remove " ` " symbol in query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5. I have tried to put the following query in my controller.

```
$projects = DB::table('projects AS prj')
                ->join('customers AS cus', 'prj.customerid', '=', 'cus.custid')
                ->leftjoin('file_assocs AS fa', 'prj.prjid', '=', 'fa.id')
                ->groupBy('fa.id','prj.prjid')
                ->select('count(fa.id) as filecount', 'prj.name as proj_name', 'prj.prjdesp', 'cus.name as customer_name')
                ->get();
```

But it gives output likes this

```
select `count(fa`.`id)` as `filecount`, `prj`.`name` as `proj_name`, `prj`.`prjdesp`, 
       `cus`.`name` as `customer_name` 
from `projects` as `prj` inner 
join `customers` as `cus` on `prj`.`customerid` = `cus`.`custid` 
left join `file_assocs` as `fa` on `prj`.`prjid` = `fa`.`id` 
group by `fa`.`id`, `prj`.`prjid`
```

This is not giving my output. Because in my `count(fa.id)` as showned here as

```
`count(fa`.`id)`
```

So it shows error. Is there any way to remove the " ` " symbol in laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `DB::raw()`

```
$projects = DB::table('projects AS prj')
    ->join('customers AS cus', 'prj.customerid', '=', 'cus.custid')
    ->leftjoin('file_assocs AS fa', 'prj.prjid', '=', 'fa.id')
    ->groupBy('fa.id','prj.prjid')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(fa.id) as filecount, prj.name as proj_name, prj.prjdesp, cus.name as customer_name'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: I have tried but it giving `Call to a member function count() on a non-object` error

Comment: Are you calling count() method anywhere in your code. If so please post that code.

Comment: I have used `$file_count = count($files);` in my `controllers store`function

Comment: Can you post the code where from where the error is throwing according to the line number and file associated with

Comment: Got my answer. I have used wrong count() method in my view.